# Platform-independent and thread-safe logging solution

Tags: c++, c, logs, log-analysis

I'm looking for a possibility to log events in my C/C++ application. This solution should

- be fast and easy to use
- compile and work under Windows and Linux
- be thread-safe
- not damage the logfile when application crashes in between
- provide a viewer where e.g. log entries can be shown/hidden dependent on their severity

So...are there any recommendations for this? I'd guess there exists something like this, I can't be the first with this requirement...

Thanks for evey sugestion and idea!

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you tried any of the standard log libraries? Why don't they suit your needs?

Comment: @holroy what standard log libraries do provide a viewer for the log files?